# Bad type on operand stack Error Java ASM ClassVisitor

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I'm using a plugin for Eclipse (WindowBuilder) in my RCP application based on Eclipse. Since a few versions this plugin doesn't work anymore in my RCP setup. In Eclipse however there is no problem.

It seems to be a reflective access error related to the ASM library.

In the logs I found an error message which indicates that this is caused by a wrong given type to a ASM ClassVisitor method.

Here the shortened error message:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
Location:
org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/reflect/ProjectClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; @140: invokevirtual
Reason:
Type 'org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/reflect/AbstractMethodsImplementorVisitor' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor'
Current Frame:
bci: @140
flags: { }
locals: { 'org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/reflect/ProjectClassLoader', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/io/InputStream', '[B', 'org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader', 'org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/reflect/AbstractMethodsImplementorVisitor' }
stack: { 'org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader', 'org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/utils/reflect/AbstractMethodsImplementorVisitor', integer }
Bytecode:......
```

The question is can this error be caused by a wrong bytecode version?

What else can cause this kind of error or how have I to read this ASM library error?

Comment: There is not much we can do, given this little amount of information. It’s clear that the original code expected `AbstractMethodsImplementorVisitor` to be a subclass of `ClassVisitor`, but it isn’t at verification time. Either, because the class hierarchy of `AbstractMethodsImplementorVisitor` changed after compiling or you have an issue of multiple class loaders having a class of the same name. Though, in the latter case, I’d rather expect a `LinkageError` with the message “loader constraint violation”.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this is the only error message I get in the log files only. I also thought about a class loader issue. But a more detailed error message would help.